# How to create a fluid graph animation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, graph, swift

inspired by the the animated graph from Joe Ski on his [dribbles profile](https://dribbble.com/shots/1694287-Animated-Graph?list=searches&offset=27) I wonder where to start if I want to implement something like this on iOS.

Is `CoreGraphics` and `drawRect` combined with `NSTimer` the right starting point? Where comes `CoreAnimation` into the game? Or is `CorePlot` the platform to build on?

Can you please advice me where I have to dig into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start by exploring the `Core Animation` framework and have some knowledge about `Core Graphics`. This is how I would go about it:

1. Define your shapes with `UIBezierPaths`
2. Define the target shapes with different paths
3. Animate the "path" key with `CABasicAnimation` between the start and target paths

Happy exploring!

Comment: what does alternative shapes mean in here?

Comment: I meant what is the difference between 1 and 2? Can you be a bit more specific please :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you'd like to implement an advanced custom animation, I think you should start with [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) (and [`CVDisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvdisplaylink-k0k) for MacOS).

`CADisplayLink` allows you to intervene every single time the screen is refreshed, e.g: ~60 times/second if you are having 60fps.

If you look at its examples, you'll see that it also gives you timing information so that you don't need to rely on `NSTimer` which doesn't go well with animations actually.

In you particular case, as Mundi said, `CABasicAnimation` might be enough as well.

Also, you can follow [`BAFluidView`](https://github.com/antiguab/BAFluidView/blob/master/Pod/Classes/BAFluidView.m) example on Github which uses `CAKeyframeAnimation` to achieve something similar.